# how to rationalize $\frac{1}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c+\sqrt d+e}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let say $a, b, c, d, e \in \Bbb Z^+ $ and $\sqrt a, \sqrt b, \sqrt c, \sqrt d \notin \Bbb Z^+ $

My problem is how to rationalize the denominator of $\frac{1}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c+\sqrt d+e}$

is this can be rationalized? what is the "term" to multiply both the numerator and the denominator?

I tried to rationaliz by multiplying $\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c-\sqrt d+e$

and another time by multiplying $\sqrt a+\sqrt b-\sqrt c-\sqrt d+e$ but didn't successes

can you tell how to rationaliz or a hint also would appreciate

Thanks.

Comment: multiply numerator and denominator by the product of all fifteen expressions $\pm\sqrt a\pm\sqrt b\cdots+e$ apart from the original

Comment: What does "rationalize" mean? (Do you want to get rid of the roots at denominator)?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown can you tell what is the answer if we multiply all 16 expressions $\sqrt a\pm \sqrt b\pm \sqrt c\pm \sqrt d+e$

Comment: @NoChance changing $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ to $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$

Comment: @BadEnglish, thanks-I have bad English!

Comment: Try it first for ${1\over \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+e}$ and see if the answer looks more useful than the original.  While you can rationalize the denominator by following Lord Shark's suggestion, I'm not sure you'll like the answer once you get it.

Comment: You don't want to rationalise the fraction -- you can't since it's irrational. What you want to do is to rationalise its denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you have that, $$\Pi_{(i_1,\dots, i_n)\in C_2^n}((-1)^{i_1}\sqrt{a_1}+\dots+(-1)^{i_n}\sqrt{a_n})$$ is an integer,

where $a_i$ is an integer $\forall i$.

Can you prove this?

---

I think an elementary proof may be this:

The polynomial
 $$\Pi_{(i_1,\dots, i_n)\in C_2^n} ((-1)^{i_1}X_1+\dots+(-1)^{i_n}X_n)$$
is clearly even on each of its variables, then it must be quadratic on each of its variables (meaning that it can be rewritten as a polynomial on $X_i^2$). And this concludes.

Comment: is there any equal sign anywhere?
is it proving by induction?

Comment: I think you can prove it by induction. I know it's true trough some elementary galois theory, are you familiar with that?

Comment: I am not familiar with this, but I will try to prove this thanks.

Comment: Edit: I made some mistakes in the way I wrote it before

Comment: is it equal to something? I still didn't understand the property you have given

Comment: The point is that it is an integer, so you can make the denominator an integer